# Cannot forward after response has been committed - Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to logout from the HTTPSession and redirect the user to the login page.

Below is my complete Http servlet code as is.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    super.doGet(req, resp);
    processRequest(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    super.doPost(req, resp);
    processRequest(req, resp);
}

private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    final HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) 
    {
        session.invalidate();
    }

    response.sendRedirect("/login.html");
    //getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.html").forward(request, response);
}
```

}

But getting the below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
at com.controller.LogoutServlet.processRequest(LogoutServlet.java:41)
```

Comment: Post the code of your servlet from where you're calling processRequest()

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: Modified the above question with full code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove calls to

```
super.doGet(req, resp); // and
super.doPost(req, resp);
```

The Base class implementations simply try to throw an error message that GET or POST is not supported.

```
// HttpServlet#doGet() calls
resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, msg);
```

The above line is what has already committed the response.

Comment: Awesome it works good. Any particular reason why this has to be removed?

Comment: This is part of the RequestDispatcher.forward(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) method description: "forward should be called before the response has been committed to the client (before response body output has been flushed). If the response already has been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException. Uncommitted output in the response buffer is automatically cleared before the forward". You are committing the response with those super calls

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you redirect instead of forward?

```
    response.sendRedirect("/login.html");
```

Comment: Below is the exception I get if I redirect : java.lang.IllegalStateException
 org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:473)
 com.controller.LogoutServlet.processRequest(LogoutServlet.java:41)
 com.controller.LogoutServlet.doGet(LogoutServlet.java:23)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)